# 9 patch image as background for TextInputEditText and icon position

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, nine-patch

I set a 9 patch image as background on the TextInputEditText layout. The problem is that the error icon and the eye icon are on the wrong position:

[image]

How can i fix?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:errorText="@{viewModel.passwordError}"
                        
                        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/login_editText_password"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="@string/fui_password_hint"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:background="@drawable/shadow_form"
                            android:text="@={viewModel.passwordLoginValue}"
                            android:afterTextChanged="@{() -> viewModel.onCredentialsTextChanged()}" />

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You have to remove `android:background="@drawable/shadow_form"` in your `TextInputEditText`

Comment: please share file login_show_password_selector

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the reason of this question is that i need that background for that blue shadow effect.

Comment: @JavadDehban doesn't matter, if i use the standard eye icon i have the same problem.

Comment: @Atomico It is clear but the `TextInputLayout` uses a `FrameLayout` for the `EditText` and the endIcon and sets the proper background on it. If you want to use a similar layout just don't use a `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Oh ok now i understand, any idea on how can I achieve that effect?

Comment: @Atomico You can an `EditText` with an `android:drawableEnd=""` but you have to implement the clickListener.